# Eclipse MinGW undefined reference to SDL functions

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, sdl

So I've been searching for nigh on two hours now, haven't found a single working solution. I'm using SDL 2.0.4, and all the libraries are for the x64 architecture. I don't get the errors with SDL v1, but I need some of the newer functions. Here's what's coming up:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -o Winchester.exe "src\\Winchester.o" -lmingw32 -lSDL2 
src\Winchester.o: In function `SDL_main':
C:\Users\inigo\workspace\Winchester\Debug/../src/Winchester.c:17: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
C:\Users\inigo\workspace\Winchester\Debug/../src/Winchester.c:20: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
C:\Users\inigo\workspace\Winchester\Debug/../src/Winchester.c:22: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
C:\Users\inigo\workspace\Winchester\Debug/../src/Winchester.c:26: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateRenderer'
C:\Users\inigo\workspace\Winchester\Debug/../src/Winchester.c:28: undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
C:\Users\inigo\workspace\Winchester\Debug/../src/Winchester.c:29: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
C:\Users\inigo\workspace\Winchester\Debug/../src/Winchester.c:36: undefined reference to `SDL_PollEvent'
C:\Users\inigo\workspace\Winchester\Debug/../src/Winchester.c:39: undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyRenderer'
C:\Users\inigo\workspace\Winchester\Debug/../src/Winchester.c:40: undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help?

Comment: This bit of the error message: "error: ld returned 1 exit status", gives you the hint of what is wrong.  `ld` is the linker, it is responsible for combining all your object files and required libraries together into a single executable (very simplistic description, I know).  So, most likely, you are not providing the required libraries to the linker and thus the linker can't fine implementation for those functions.  I am sure there is somewhere in the the GUI for eclipse that you can specify both the libraries that you need, as well as where those libraries are found.